# Laravel backpack dashboard suddenly blank during development, what it could be the problem behind it?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

[image]

**As shown in picture, dashboard become blank. I do not even have clue how it does ?**

It does not mean it does not have sidebar content or something else, We had used it another project also thats working fine.

`Development/Local Environment`

`"backpack/crud": "^3.4",`

`"laravel/framework": "5.6.*",`

Comment: is the database blank?
Are there any console errors?

Comment: I checked it once again now, after your call. DB is filled now.

Comment: Hmm... I see you're using a custom dashboard.blade.php file. Are you sure it's not from something you did there? I would try using the _default_ dashboard file (the empty one provided by Backpack). If that solves the problem, it means it's the custom dashboard.blade.php file.

Comment: @tabacitu thanks for your reply, I did it. Actually it was at my code level problem